# changing "with" property changes styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I have html that looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr onclick="show();">
            <td class="cell">Click to open</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="display:none; position:absolute; left:150px" id="hiddenDiv">
    <table data-bind="with: someProperty">
        <tr onclick="hide();">
            <td class="cell" data-bind="text:message"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Color cells" onclick="colorCells()" />
```

And my JavaScript looks like this:

```
    function show() {
        vm.someProperty(vm.list[1]);
        $("#hiddenDiv").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    function hide() {
        $("#hiddenDiv").fadeOut("slow");
    }
    function colorCells() {
        $(".cell").css("background-color", "Yellow");
    }

    function ViewModel() {
        this.list = [new SubModel("item 1"), new SubModel("item 2")];
        this.someProperty = ko.observable(this.list[0]);
    }

    function SubModel(msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }

    var vm = new ViewModel();

    $(function () {    
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
```

I set up a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mkP9r/2/).

Now the problem is, when you click the button, all the table cells with class "cell" should have their background color changed. However, if the hidden div isn't visible, then when it is made visible, it's background color is still white. The reason for this seems to be because I'm changing the property that is used in a "with" binding that wraps the hidden cell. It seems when you change the property bound with "with", it resets the style for it's subitems.

(If that makes no sense, do this on the jsFiddle. Click the button, then click the "Click to open" cell. Notice that "item 2" isn't highlighted. Click the button again and it'll be highlighted. Now click the "Click to open" cell again, notice that "item 2" is no longer highlighted. Now remove the line that sets "someProperty" in the show function and repeat the experiment. "item 1" is now highlighted correctly regardless of whether or not it was visible when you click the color cells button)

Is this by design? Is there a way to work around it so that changing a property used by "with" doesn't reset the style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to solve this problem, IMHO, would be put the color also as an observable, which can be changed onclick of the button. I have the update [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mkP9r/3/)

Comment: Hmmm...you might be on to something. My real example is a lot more complicated, but I think I can make that work.

Comment: Actually, I'd hope to use color animation using the jQuery.color() plugin. Not sure if I can do that if it's a view model ko.observable?

Comment: If there is some bit of logic involved in the color animation, like in your case using the color() plugin, you might want to look at making the color as a ko.computed() to which you can pass in a function to be executed. Another suggestion I had is to also move the show(), hide(), and colorCells() method to inside the View Model and then use the "click" data-binding to wire it up to the ViewModel method. That way both the data and the command logic is contained within the ViewModel and your solution becomes as close to the MVVM pattern definition, based on which knockoutjs was created.

Comment: In the end, I did a simple custom binding to handle the color animation. Seems to work.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. KnockoutJS is really cool, now that I've been using it in a couple of projects. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering the css class, try altering the class of the cells and not the css class 'cell' itself, see if that works?