# Knockout - when does a template re-render

Tags: knockout.js

We have a simple template which switches between editable and not editable. Basically it just hides input field and shows a span, or the other way around.

```
<script type="text/html" id="inputTextTemplate">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: field, visible: $data.isEdit" />
    <span data-bind="text: field, visible: !$data.isEdit"></span>
</script>
```

We also have some styles which we apply through JQuery, but the problem is that every time the template switches from editable and not editable it is re-rendered and those styles are gone.

Here is a jsFiddle of the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/uCWx4/4/

Why is this happening? How can we fix this so the template is rendered only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that I was sending it a value, not an observable. If I make an observable or computed, then template is rendered only once.
So before the call to template was

```
isEdit: isEdit() == 'true'
```

if I create a computed

```
this.isEditable = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.isEdit() == 'true';
});
```

and call it with

```
isEdit: isEditable
```

it works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/uCWx4/8/

Comment: In my example it's a string, because radio buttons set it to 'true' or 'false'. If I just do `return self.isEdit();` then 'false' will also be true.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following thing:
**HTML Code**

I've added css class for both controls like this `css: { first: $data.isEdit }` and this `css: { second: !$data.isEdit }`

```
    <script type="text/html" id="inputTextTemplate">
        <input type="text" data-bind="css: { first: $data.isEdit }, value: field, visible: $data.isEdit" />
        <span data-bind="css: { second: !$data.isEdit }, text: field, visible: !$data.isEdit">   </span>
    </script>
```

And some **CSS**

```
​.first{
  color: red;
}
.second{
  color: blue;
}
```

​
Please read [official documentation about css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)

Also, here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/dGLey/)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it doesn't help in this case. I should elaborate the question a bit. We also do some event wiring, focus, blur, JQuery ui controls... which can't be done through css.

Answer (score 0):

You fiddle doesn't actually have any styles applied through jQuery, but I encountered a similar problem when using [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143670/changing-with-property-changes-styles).

The solution is to not do it. Think about whether you can apply your styles in your template using an observable in your ViewModel instead. Or else you will need to reapply those styles through jQuery every time you rerender your template.